# MongoDB - EDITOR variable - MongoDB shell - Windows 7

Tags: mongodb, shell

Is the EDITOR variable feature really working on Windows 7?

I am reading a text saying that once we set the EDITOR variable
in .mongorc.js we can just type in the shell: **edit var_name**
and **var_name** will be loaded in the EDITOR (UltraEdit in my case)
for editing. Once we're done making the changes, we can just
***save and exit the editor; then the variable will be parsed

and loaded back into the shell.*** The part in bold italic
does not work for me.

All it does is offering me to save some js file on my desktop?!

Any ideas?

EDIT:

*I noticed that if I set it to Notepad ("notepad.exe"),

it works OK. But if I set it to UltraEdit ("uedit32.exe"),

it does not work the way one would expect.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `EDITOR` environment variable works on Windows, but it looks like there are a few factors that affect usability as at MongoDB 2.4.

When you use the `edit` command, the `mongo` shell writes a temporary JavaScript file with the contents of that variable and [launches the external editor](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/v2.4/src/mongo/shell/dbshell.cpp#L561) with this file path. The shell session then waits for the editor to exit and *checks the return code*.

This doesn't work well if:

- the external editor has a multiple-document interface and there are already other documents open
- the external editor doesn't return the expected 0 (no errors) return code

#### Workarounds

- Limit yourself to using a single document editor for your `EDITOR` setting. While `notepad.exe` works, there is likely a more capable editor that includes JavaScript syntax highlighting.
- If you are developing complex JavaScript functions, you probably want to have those in an external file. You can use [`load("/path/to/file.js")`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/load/) to reload the latest version of a JS file into the shell.

#### UltraEdit

UltraEdit has some extra user experience wrinkles (I tested with UltraEdit V20):

- (works with luck) if you **don't** have UltraEdit open before you invoke `edit` from the `mongo` shell *and* don't open any extra tabs, it will work as an external editor. You should be able to successfully use `edit` from the `mongo` shell to launch UltraEdit, edit a variable, and see the results saved when you close UltraEdit. UltraEdit prompts to save the updated JS file in the same location.
- (doesn't work) if UltraEdit was **already open** and has other document tabs, it has different behaviour. The `edit` command from the `mongo` shell will open a new tab, but when you close this tab (to save changes) UltraEdit prompts with a "Save as" dialog. UltraEdit saves the JS file, but apparently doesn't return the expected exit code so the `mongo` shell is unaware that the JS file has been updated and should be reloaded.

EDIT: Thanks to UltraEdit Expert's suggestions, I found a configuration setting that makes UltraEdit work nicely:

- Open the Configuration settings (**Advanced > Configuration** menu)
- Under **Application Layout > Miscellaneous** enable the checkbox for the setting **Maintain separate process for each file opened from external application**
- Restart UltraEdit (the setting doesn't appear to take effect until the next launch)

With the "separate process" setting enabled, you should now be able to use UltraEdit as an external `EDITOR` and see the changes reflected when you close the editing tab opened from the `mongo` shell.

Comment: I pondered raising an improvement suggestion in the [MongoDB issue tracker](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER), but I'm not sure there is a better way for an external editor to generically indicate "I'm done editing". This usage of the `$EDITOR` variable is consistent with other Linux/Unix applications. If you need something fancier you may want to consider alternative [Administration Interfaces](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/administration-interfaces/) to see if there is something that better suits your workflow.

Comment: I am using notpad++ and it was not saving my file. Ensuring only one file was opening in the editor allowed this to work correctly. With multiple files open, the mongo-opened js file did not save.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is an addition on what Stennie wrote already above which was too long to add it as a comment.

It looks like `mongo` determines file change not by watching the file status (file size, file dates, file attributes) of the file passed to the called editor, but the execution state of the called editor application.

UltraEdit is configured by default to open all files in same instance. Therefore every call of uedit32.exe with one or more file names on command line results in starting a new instance of UltraEdit which loads the configuration settings, detects that a single instance should be used, and searches next in process list for an already running instance of UltraEdit. If there is already another instance of UltraEdit, the just started instance  passes the names of the files to open to the other instance of UltraEdit and then terminates itself.

This behavior looks like nothing was changed on the file within the called editor for `mongo`.

There are several possibilities to change this behavior so that an instance of UltraEdit is always used when uedit32.exe is called by `mongo` with a file to edit.

First, there is the command line option `/fni` which means "force new instance". If this command line option is used in the editor's definition as first parameter after uedit32.exe, the new instance of UltraEdit created by the call of `mongo` never looks for an already running instance and opens all files on its command line in its own instance.

Second, the configuration item **Miscellaneous** in branch **Application Layout** of the **Configuration** in menu **Advanced** could be opened and the setting *Allow multiple instances* could be checked to work by default with multiple instances of UltraEdit.

Third, with setting *Allow multiple instances* not enabled, the setting *Maintain separate process for each file opened from external application* could be checked available since UltraEdit v18.10 to get UltraEdit working as editor for `mongo`.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the suggestions! I tried all 3 :). Adding `/fni` to the `EDITOR` variable didn't work (it confused the path parsing and the editor wouldn't launch). Setting "allow multiple instances" sort of worked .. with the caveat that you have to close UltraEdit to see the change. The final option of **"Maintain separate process"** was a winner: the `edit` command from `mongo` shell opens a new tab, and closing the tab sends the right exit code for MongoDB to reload the JavaScript file.

Comment: Adding /fni to the EDITOR variable didn't work ... I supposed that, but it was worth an attempt. Setting "allow multiple instances" sort of worked ... as settings are written only on exit to uedit32.ini, it is required to exit UltraEdit to enable this setting also for other instances of UltraEdit started after changing this setting and reading it from same uedit32.ini. However, the third option is perfect for this case and I'm glad that I could help. Thanks for testing all my 3 suggestions.

Comment: "Two out of three ain't bad" ;-). At least the last option worked a treat.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/getting-started-with-the-mongo-shell/) is naturally very Unix variant specific. This will be apparent in the documentation itself.

In your case, setting the variable in mongorc.js will provide something so launch on the edit command helper, but the result will not be returned as it would in the Unix way.