# editing objects from MongoDB with an external editor doesn't update the object

Tags: mongodb, editor, notepad++, mongo-shell

I'm using the Mongo shell. I've set my EDITOR to my notepad++ path. I create an object and then I use the EDIT command to edit the obeject using notepad++ but it doesn't update the object.

```
// mongo shell
var pow = { name: "teest" }; 
edit pow
// notepad++ opens a document called 'mongo_edit141225123.js' that resides
// in C:\users\...\Appdata\local\temp
// I edit the object, save and close notepad++
pow // object isn't updated :(
```

what am I missing?

Comment: Of the top of my head I would say that you are "missing" using a real operating system. But really, how is EDITOR defined in your "mongorc"?

Comment: I have the same issue if I use an external editor (textmate) on OS X (actually the file is empty when it fires up), but not if I use vim or nano which stay in the shell to do the editing.  I don't have a Windows machine to test with here (will later), so will see if the same thing is true on Windows

Comment: @NeilLunn my mongorc.js is empty :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be a few caveats here. But I can describe how I got this working:

1. Set the `PATH` environment variable to include the path to the notepad++ executable. Note to both "apply" this change and not have an existing command line window when doing so. Or at least open a new one once this step is complete.
2. Specify an `EDITOR` variable in your command shell window, or otherwise set that under the same system properties as setting the `PATH` environment variable. Since the program directory is in the PATH just set the executable name:

   ```
   set EDITOR="notepad++"
   ```
3. Launch your mongo shell and go to edit a variable:

   ```
   > edit something
   ```
4. This will launch the specified editor, with an "undefined" variable at first. Type in something "valid", as any invalid JavaScript declaration will be discarded. Now for the important part. After your edit and when "closing" click the "tab close" icon and **do not** close the entire editor as shown:

   [image]

That last part seems to be the most important. If you are prompted to save (and you likely will be ) then do so. Only "after" the tab has been closed (and saved) should you then close the editor itself.

If you then subsequently issue the same `edit something` from the mongo shell, then the editor will open with the content that you edited before.

If you **don't** follow this and just close the editor window first, then you should see an additional tab opened and the original tab with the content that you had before. But subsequent changes will be lost as the shell is now tracking a different temporary file.

So follow those steps and you should be right. I would expect there are similar issues with other external editors that will actually resolve in a similar way.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work. Also i want to note that I changed the editor to the default notepad(c:\windows\notepad.exe) and it works :| . I'm guessing that notepad++ on my computer somehow either doesn't have access to save the temporary file or i don't know...

Comment: @razvan Are you following this exactly? I was very specific about eac step as that is the only way this works. You must both save and close the tab before closing the editor

Comment: it seems to be working if i close notepad++ and all my previous tabs. guess i didn't follow your instructions correctly. The editor -shell connection seems to be the problem. I also discovered this topic regarding this problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21467138/mongodb-editor-variable-mongodb-shell-windows-7 . Thanks again and have a nice day